# Hide an element with transition, start a center not left 0

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a video element when I click on one element, video hide gradually, I modify the height property and width at 0 for each.

But when the animation is complete, the video is hide on left 0 and top 0, but I want to finish this animation at the center do you have an idea ?

Check my code please

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');

window.addEventListener('click', () => {

    div.style.width = '0'
    div.style.height = '0'

})
```

```css
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    transition: ease-in-out 2s;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: If you set `margin: 0 auto` on the div, it should remain centered while reducing the width. Alternately you can use flex box for positioning the div to the center.

Comment: You can use `div.style.transform = 'scale(0)'` https://jsfiddle.net/5f7hz3qh/

Comment: And, if my element take 100% of my width ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css property scale to scale to 0 and then apply your JS function to hide it. just add the class "scale-to-0" to your video element and then hide it.

```
div.scale-to-0  {
    -ms-transform: scale(0, 0); 
    -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0); 
    transform: scale(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, I apply this class on my element when I clicking on my element, I apply a classList.remove('scale-to-0') right ?

Comment: you should also add the css attached to your stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `margin 0 auto`?

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');

window.addEventListener('click', () => {

    div.style.width = '0'
    div.style.height = '0'

})
```

```css
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    transition: ease-in-out 2s;
margin:0 auto;

}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Is your element full width and full height of the screen?

Comment: It's ok, I use your solution above. 
Woo, a Hater just passed he put point down.....

Comment: I don't know why, but it is okay mate :)